# Xcode 4.4 constraint errors

Tags: xcode4, constraints

I am using Xcode 4.4 and creating my views in interface builder. When I run my app, I consistently get the following constraint errors.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x104486db0 h=-&- v=-&- V:[NSView:0x106a33090]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':NSClipView:0x106a0cef0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x104486e10 h=-&- v=-&- V:|-(15)-[NSView:0x106a33090]   (Names: '|':NSClipView:0x106a0cef0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1002da350 h=--& v=--& V:[NSClipView:0x106a0cef0(672)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x106a11ba0 V:[NSView:0x1044eb990]-(657)-|   (Names: '|':NSView:0x106a33090 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1044d68d0 V:|-(270)-[NSView:0x1044eb990]   (Names: '|':NSView:0x106a33090 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x100271040 V:[NSView:0x1044eb990(245)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x100271040 V:[NSView:0x1044eb990(245)]>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints 
to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.
And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
```

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each view you're intending on constraining do this:

```
[view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

That will get rid of the "NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint" parts in the log.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a way to solve this without writing code.

In the storyboard, select your super view. In the Attributes Inspector, deselect the "Autoresize Subviews" checkbox as shown below.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode 5]

This will add `autoresizesSubviews="NO"` to the storyboard XML file. In my case, the XML already contained `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO"`, however, this did not stop autolayout from creating `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint`s.

*Note: Maybe my answer applies to **Xcode 5** only, as I can't check if Xcode 4.4 already had this checkbox. But since Google still turns up this SO question when searching `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint`, it might benefit someone.*